# How to delay my each thread group in JMeter (without using startup delay)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-3.2

Here I have 4 Thread Groups present in my Test Plan and I have a requirement, need to run test plan in the time interval of 30 minutes between each of my Thread Group (2nd thread group should start only after 30 minutes, after the completion of 1st thread group and so on).

[image]

But cannot estimate the actual duration for all my thread groups. And my Ramp-up period should be 0 for all my thread groups, is there any solution to full fill my requirement ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

1. Add [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) to the end of each Thread Group
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Target: `Current Thread`
   - Action: `Pause`
   - Duration: `1800000`
3. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the Test Action sampler and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to number of threads in the current Thread Group

This way Test Action sampler will act as a "rendezvous point" so all threads in the current Thread Group will sleep for `1800000` milliseconds (1800 seconds == 30 minutes), this way you will get a 30 minutes delay between Thread Groups.

Comment: Should I need to give value in Timeout in milliseconds in Synchronizing Timer ?  Till the entire test plan gets completed its execution, I cannot see the result of single thread group (ie] 1st thread group) ? Even though I kept a listener at the end of each thread group I cannot view my thread group results in between the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Dmitri T answer, Make sure in Test Plan the **uncheck** `Run Thread Groups Consecutively` so it won't try to execute in parallel

You can add [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) in each Thread Group as the parent of all other components with same name (default is global_lock)

That way no Thread Group will start until previous thread ends.

**EDIT**

For getting result between threads:
Add to each thread group [Generate Summary Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Generate_Summary_Results) to get the result of each thread

> Generates a summary of the test run so far to the log file and/or standard output.

Answer (score 1):

I use like this :

Add "Flow Control Action" steps in Sampler List to the end of the Thread Groups

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).